# In android, onCheckedChanged of a Radiogroup is not triggered when I Programmatically set a Radiobutton by call setChecked(true)

Tags: android

In my application, I need to programmatically set a radiobutton and expect the onCheckedChanged of a Radiogroup to be triggered so that I can do something in it.

Code to set a radiobutton programmatically.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
 RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.footer_btn_course);
 btn.setChecked(true);
```

And in another activity, I did something like:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.footer_radio);
            mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            if(btn != null){
                  do_something();
            }
      }
  }
```

However, looks like this way doesn't work, the onCheckedChanged was never called. Anyone know what I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To fire a radio check box for the default when initializing. Set everything to unchecked with the clearCheck method. Then, set the handler and finally set the default and your handler will fire.

```
itemtypeGroup.clearCheck();
```

then, same as usual add a listener:

```
mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.footer_radio);
            mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            mRadioGroup.clearCheck();

RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.footer_btn_course);
btn.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: if you're adding `android:checked="true"` in your xml then `mRadioGroup.clearCheck();` is mandatory else not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for the issue, but it may be you miss refer your radio group id.
Try this instead to see the effect (inside your `onCreate()`):

```
RadioGroup rdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.footer_radio);
    rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            if(btn != null){
                  do_something();
            }
        }
    });
```

Or may be `(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId)` return null.

Try `Spinner` if your case gets ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `btn.setChecked(true)`;

Used `btn.performClick();` this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem..

and here is my approach:

```
 class Myclass extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupDecisionUncertain);
            radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonNo_U);
            radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobuttonYes_U);
// declare the onCheckChangedListener
radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (checkedId == radio1.getId()) { //do something

                } else { // do other thing
                }

            }
        });

radiogroup.check(radio1.getId());


}
}
```

***Notice that i set the checked radio button after registering the listener..***

Answer (score 0):

Implement `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `RadioGroup.onCheckedChangeListene`r that will work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
.....

}
```