# Android - CheckedChangeListener is not working when programmatically checking radiobutton(inside radiogroup)

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have an activity in which i am hiding/unhiding some layouts and views based on the checked state of a `radiobutton`(inside radiogroup).
But when i programmatically check the `radiobutton` the `checkedchangelistener` is not working. But works fine when i check the `radiobutton` manually.
This is my `checkedChangeListener` :
ll - `LinearLayout`
edt - `EditText`

```
rg_listing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()

                                          {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                                  switch (checkedId) {
                                                      case R.id.rb_auction:
                                                          listing_type = "auction";
                                                          ll_ps.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          edt_startB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                          edt_resP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                          btn_startB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                          btn_resP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                          break;
                                                      case R.id.rb_fixedprice:
                                                          listing_type = "fixed price";
                                                          ll_ps.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          edt_startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          edt_resP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          btn_startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          btn_resP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          break;
                                                      case R.id.rb_privatesale:
                                                          listing_type = "private sale";
                                                          ll_ps.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                          edt_startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          edt_resP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          btn_startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          btn_resP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                          break;
                                                      default:
                                                          System.out.println("Error in switch");
                                                          break;
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }

    );
```

I have tried `radiobutton.performClick()`, `radiobutton.setChecked()`, `radiogroup.check()`...

Any help is much appreciated....!!!

Comment: did you already try all the answers to this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310818/) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17746307/5251407 this worked Thanks @0X0nosugar